# Confuse with relative path for subfolder

Tags: paths, relative

Sorry as maybe this question is a bit rhetorical,

I have my main latex file in

```
C:/latex/thesis.tex
```

while i split my other chapters in another chapters folder

```
C:/latex/chapters/
```

and my images are in a folder by itself

```
C:/latex/images/
```

The problem is in my chapter tex file, I am unable to locate my images. Appreciate someone can direct to me what is the best way to locate my images.

Currently, I have set

```
%!TEX root = ../thesis.tex
```

at the beginning of every chapter .tex files

and when I call images:

```
\includegraphics[height=.4\textwidth]{images/general-scheduling}
```

I got the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `images/general-scheduling' not found
```

Comment: use `\graphicspath{}` in the preamble to set your path to the images. then simply call them by their file name. and welcome to TeX.sx

Comment: It depends on the folder where you are when you start to compile thesis.tex. If you are in C:\latex, then `\includegraphics[height=.4\textwidth]{images/general-scheduling}` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so familiar with windows relative path but in UNIX systems you should use:

```
\includegraphics[height=.4\textwidth]{../images/general-scheduling}
```

With `images/general-scheduling` LaTeX will seek for the images in `chapters/image/` so a wrong path.

Comment: But as the root files sits in `C:/latex/thesis.tex` shouldn't it be `\includegraphics[height=.4\textwidth]{./images/general-scheduling}`?